# How and why is string.isdigit() locale dependent?

Tags: python, locale, digit

Python has the function for string to test whether all characters are digits: [`string.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).

In the manual is written:

> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent

How is this method locale-depedent? In what locales are there digits that are outside the 0-9 range?

Also, if this is locale dependent, does python have a method for checking it with a specific locale (i.e. only 0-9 digits).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyphs_used_with_the_Hindu-Arabic_numeral_system#Symbols

Comment: I think to manual just means that the actual 8-bit character codes are locale-dependent, not that the characters aren't 0-9.

Answer (score 4):

CPython uses the C function "isdigit" for the is_digit method on strings (see stringobject.c). See this related thread:  [Can isdigit legitimately be locale dependent in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898228/can-isdigit-legitimately-be-locale-dependent-in-c)

Apparently, it has to do with superscript digits, like 0xB2 ('²'), 0xB3 ('³') and 0xB9 ('¹').

HTH

Answer (score 1):

> does python have a method for checking it with a specific locale (i.e. only 0-9 digits).

The simplest way:

```
>>> '1' in '1234567890'
True
>>> 'a' in '1234567890'
False
```

Your can also check `ord`, it <strike>*might* be faster</strike> ([isn't](http://ideone.com/SwVTx)):

```
>>> ord('0') <= ord('a') <= ord('9')
False
>>> ord('0') <= ord('5') <= ord('9')
True
```

Comment: Looking a global function and calling it, three times, shouldn't be faster than loading a local and doing 10 character comparisons in C.

Comment: This only checks a character, not a whole string of digits.

Comment: You can apply this to a sequence using `all(function(e) for e in seq)`.