# Why is parameter to isdigit integer?

Tags: c++

The function [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is:

```
  int isdigit(int ch);
```

The return (Non-zero value if the character is a numeric character, zero otherwise.) smells like the function was inherited from C, but even that does not explain why the parameter type is `int` not `char` while at the same time...

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as
>   unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.

Is there any technical reason why `isdigits`takes an `int` not a `char`?

Comment: EOF is the reason. That's a valid input to the function

Comment: It's my conjecture that in the early days of C, the preference was to use `int`s for these functions for performance reasons since `int` is meant to be the natural type of a platform.

Comment: @StoryTeller I had this idea just 1 sec before posting the question, so I posted it anyhow ;)

Comment: Also because these kind of functions are intended to handle Unicode characters via locales, and those don't always fit in a single `char`, thus `int` is used instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit).

Comment: It gets more interesting when you ask about memchr() and strset().

Comment: @HansPassant thats really scary stuff. `isdigit` was already a small shock for me, but you are causing me nightmares

Comment: @RSahu Prior to the introduction of function prototypes, it was flat out impossible to pass a `char` without it undergoing promotion to `int` (or `unsigned int`).

Comment: @hvd, thanks for that insight. That makes more sense than performance as the reason. That probably also explains the functions in math.h use `double` as argument types.

Comment: It all comes from C, after all C++ comes from C and therefore inherits a lot from that langue. isdigit is used alongside functions like getchar(), which reads a character from a statement and returns an int. also good to remember that char is just an internal type with very small range.

Comment: when functions that come from C are about receiving, or providing character into int, character is assumed to be a char that has been cast to an unsigned char (so that it is always positive, negative values overflowing into the top half of its range) and then put into an int. also remember internally the int value that is passed to isdigit gets converted to ASCII value for check.

Comment: @RemyLebeau cppref says something else : [isdigit and isxdigit are the only standard narrow character classification functions that are not affected by the currently installed C locale.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)

Comment: @tobi303: true, however [Microsoft doesn't follow that rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898228/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reaons is to allow `EOF` as input. And `EOF` is (from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c)):

> EOF   integer constant expression of type int and negative value

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but I believe the question deserves more detail.

A `char` in C++ is either signed or unsigned depending on your implementation (and, yet, it's a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char`).

Where C grew up, `char` was typically unsigned and assumed to be an *n*-bit byte that could represent [0..2^n-1].  (Yes, there were some machines that had byte sizes other than 8 bits.)  In fact, `char`s were considered virtually indistinguishable from bytes, which is why functions like `memcpy` take `char *` rather than something like `uint8_t *`, why `sizeof char` is always 1, and why `CHAR_BITS` isn't named `BYTE_BITS`.

But the C standard, which was the baseline for C++, only promised that `char` could hold any value in the execution character set.  They might hold additional values, but there was no guarantee.  The source character set (basically 7-bit ASCII minus some control characters) required something like 97 values.  For a while, the execution character set could be smaller, but in practice it almost never was.  Eventually there was an explicit requirement that a `char` be large enough to hold an 8-bit byte.

But the range was still uncertain.  If unsigned, you could rely on [0..255].  Signed chars, however, could--in theory--use a sign+magnitude representation that would give you a range of [-127..127].  Note that's only 255 unique values, not 256 values ([-128..127]) like you'd get from two's complement.  If you were language lawyerly enough, you could argue that you cannot store every possible value of an 8-bit byte in a `char` even though that was a fundamental assumption throughout the design of the language and its run-time library.  I think C++ finally closed that apparent loophole in C++17 or C++20 by, in effect, requiring that a signed `char` use two's complement even if the larger integral types use sign+magnitude.

When it came time to design fundamental input/output functions, they had to think about how to return a value or a signal that you've reached the end of the file.  It was decided to use a special value rather than an out-of-band signaling mechanism.  But what value to use?  The Unix folks generally had [128..255] available and others had [-128..-1].

But that's only if you're working with text.  The Unix/C folks thought of textual characters and binary byte values as the same thing.  So `getc()` was also for reading bytes from a binary file.  All 256 possible values of a `char`, regardless of its signedness, were already claimed.

K&R C (before the first ANSI standard) didn't require function prototypes. The compiler made assumptions about parameter and return types.  This is why C and C++ have the "default promotions," even though they're less important now than they once were.  In effect, you couldn't return anything smaller than an `int` from a function.  If you did, it would just be converted to `int` anyway.

The natural solution was therefore to have `getc()` return an `int` containing either the character value *or* a special end-of-file value, imaginatively dubbed `EOF`, a macro for -1.

The default promotions not only mandated a function couldn't return an integral type smaller than an `int`, they also made it difficult to pass in a small type.  So `int` was also the natural parameter type for functions that expected a character.  And thus we ended up with function signatures like `int isdigit(int ch)`.

If you're a Posix fan, this is basically all you need.

For the rest of us, there's a remaining gotcha:  If your `char`s are signed, then -1 might represent a legitimate character in your execution character set.  How can you distinguish between them?

The answer is that functions don't really traffic in `char` values at all.  They're really using `unsigned char` values dressed up as `int`s.

```
    int x = getc(source_file);
    if (x != EOF) { /* reached end of file */ }
    else if (0 <= x && x < 128) { /* plain 7-bit character */ }
    else if (128 <= x && x < 256) {
      // Here it gets interesting.
      bool b1 = isdigit(x);  // OK
      bool b2 = isdigit(static_cast<char>(x));  // NOT PORTABLE
      bool b3 = isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(x));  // CORRECT!
    }
```